# IoT Agent provisioning

Tags: iot, fiware

I'm using these provisioning for service and device in my IoT Agent.

```
{  
   "services":[  
      {  
         "resource":"/iot/d",
         "apikey":"1234",
         "type":"multiSensor"
      }
   ]
}

{  
   "devices":[  
      {  
         "device_id":"myDeviceId",
         "entity_name":"LivingRoomSensor",
         "entity_type":"multiSensor",
         "attributes":[  
            {  
               "name":"a",
               "type":"celsius"
            },
            {  
               "name":"b",
               "type":"degrees"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

and I noticed that the attribute "type" in services can be also named "entity_type" and it must be equals to "entity_type" of devices. If these attributes are not equals I've this error:

DEVICE_GROUP_NOT_FOUND","message":"Couldn\t find device group","code":404} in get group device

Anyway the IoT Agent works. Can I use only device provisioning in my IoT Agent?

Comment: The new APIs use entity_type in the service provisioning